Proposed resolution : Quoting cannot be called plagiarism
Proposed resolution : A quote which is fully accredited and formatted as a quote, is not plagiarism.
This definition is in line with all the world's dictionaries and all the world's legal sources.
Why is this resolution necessary.
My Super User account was suspended for 30 days for plagiarism, since one moderator views answers that are quote-only as plagiarism, and I had four of them (all deleted by the moderator).
This definition of plagiarism conflicts even with
SU rules
that say (italics added by myself):

Plagiarism - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your content being downvoted or deleted.

This definition already implies my above resolution, but nevertheless I got this text in my suspension message from the SU moderators:

It has come to our attention that some of your answers consist primarily of text copied from other answers or websites. This is a violation of our Terms of Service, as well as the license agreement. It is considered plagiarism.

This message puzzled me enough to cause me to look deeper into the question.
My research on Super User.
Since I had some time on my hands these last 30 days, I have studied the Stack Exchange API and have written a program that scans all answers on Super User and checks whether they are quote-only.
Here are my results :

The moderator that suspended me has written enough quote-only answers to be suspended himself.
Another moderator has written many quote-only answers. I remark that his answers are to the point and were often accepted by the posters. I'm puzzled by him not coming forward to explain to the other moderator that quoting is not plagiarism.
There are thousands of quote-only answers on Super User and it's simply unfeasible to delete them, as many are upvoted or accepted by the posters. Deleting these answers will leave their questions in a chaotic state.

Questions to the moderators.
The above research motivates me to ask this of the moderators:
Why was I suspended for so long for a rule that doesn't exist in a written form? A rule that actually conflicts with the written rules? A rule that seems to be generally unknown and is not followed or enforced, not even by the moderators themselves?
And more: Why do unwritten rules even exist here? How can we be expected to adhere to unknown and undefined rules? For example, are answers counted as plagiarism if they have less than 20% of unquoted text, or what? Can users feel safe knowing that they may be sanctioned for unknown rules?
And most important: Super User is said to be a democracy. A democracy is ruled according to a set of written rules, and only by those rules. The rules apply to everyone and even for the persons in authority. How can we have in Super User unwritten rules that are applied or not at the discretion of the moderator?
Suggestion
I suggest that the moderators accept my above resolution in order to terminate with this issue.
If the moderators choose instead to uphold this plagiarism rule, explicitly or by inaction, I intend to fully cooperate with them by publishing on Meta Super User in bunches the links to all the quote-only answers on Super User, and I will report periodically on the progress done by the moderators in cleaning Super User of plagiarism.
Some answers to moderator Journeyman Geek.

You're not going to know which moderator suspended you.

Of course I can - when that moderator says that my answers were deleted, and you're the one that deleted them, it doesn't take great genius to understand who that moderator is.
Another great hint is that I have taken to Meta all my three suspensions, and it was you the only moderator that defended the suspensions. It's quite clear who is repeatedly suspending me, and never with any warning.

It'd be good to cite all your sources here, or at least show a modicium of research.

You're citing academical standards, which have no bearing on the issue at all. Ours is a Q&A site, not R&D. We write answers, not essays. The only requirement, as far as the posters are concerned, is to solve their problem,  and they will accept an answer in any format whatsoever. In fact, by deleting an answer which might contain the solution, you're mostly hurting the poster.

A great answer is a lot more than googling the question

Of course, but Super User doesn't have the monopoly on good answers. There are some great answers and blogs in other sources, for example in Stack Overflow. They don't lose any of their greatness by being quoted. If an answer on Stack Overflow also solves the poster's problem, why does it suddenly become "low quality" when quoted?

Quoting with appropriate sourcing isn't plagiarism - it is a necessary, but not completely sufficient.

It seems to me that you have just admitted that I have not commited plagiarism, as all my answers contained fully accredited quotes with links. Might it be that you have used the wrong reason for my suspension?

In the interests of full disclosure - its 30 days cause we followed the standard escalation, and this is your second suspension for this.

My first suspension for this offense was in 2017 - you're unearthing a 7-years old suspension in order to justify yourself. As there were a lot of quote-only answers posted in the last years, including regularly by moderators, I was entitled to assume that this rule didn't exist any more. A short message from you to me would have made suspension unnecessary, so why did you jump to use the big gun?

As a moderator, I generally consider suspensions to be a last resort, when other things have failed.

There was no other thing - there was never any warning, just BOUM, unless you're referring to an event from 7 years ago.

That said, do you really want to be the guy who basically decided to ruin a bunch of people's day cause you were unhappy with a moderator decision?
If you choose to flag based on using an automated script to find and flag things, it could potentially be a code of conduct violation as well.
We're going to expect you to read each one, as we do, and make a determination, and generally if we find someone's wasting our time, we're unhappy.

There is no problem with eyeballing all the links I would post. Nobody will be ruined, since you will not delete any other answer than mine or suspend anyone else than me. I won't be writing any programs that modify the site, since SE doesn't like it, especially if the program has bugs. I'm not a moderator, so it's up to you to decide on the gravity of the offense, as you have decided on mine.

I'd note we don't have any tooling that particularly helps with this

You're referring to the fact that you don't have a tool to find quote-only answers, and have then just scanned all my answers until you found four quote-only ones. Great effort, but this means that you have first decided on the punishment, and then worked to find the evidence to justify it.

I've been challenged to produce some URLs or shut up, so I chose
answers by moderator DavidPostill, mainly because he cannot be
harmed by this publication. I have run into the 30,000 characters
limit on question size, so I was only able to add here 180 URLs.
I'm a bit unclear about the definition of a quote-only answer
by moderator Journeyman Geek, but I think that almost all of them
should qualify. I have been delayed because I believe that some
corruption in the SQL database of SE is causing some years to be
missing from the indexes, so this list is also incomplete
in this respect.
I note that in my opinion these are excellent answers that should
not be changed in any way. The opinion of moderator Journeyman Geek
is much different, so I wait to see if he'll delete any of them.

Deleting file names from MFT
BitLocker: Encrypt all hard drives
Is webinternetsecurity a threat to a network and how to remove completely?
What is the range of the legacy IRQs supplied by the motherboard?
Batch Script 32 bit limitation of integer
Convert PowerPoint 1995 files to modern PowerPoint version
How much time does top command consider while finding CPU usage percentage?
What is the difference between a p2p network and a mesh network?
Why do browsers need to be told the encoding of a file?
how to hide sound recorder in windows 7
Shortcut changing in LibreOffice (Ubuntu 14.04)
Cannot suppress page numbers in MS Word 2010
No boot menu for Windows XP or Windows 7
Firefox 33 doesn't see Java Plugin
What does this "3-line to column" icon indicate about an object in SQL Developer?
Tune up utilities drive defrag ate my disk space
What is the difference between android and droid?
linux ls -l 5th column header size units?
Discovering the VoIP connection parameters for CISCO 7961
Getting ip adress away from network
How to get the domain controller time sync event?
How does a client know when a https or https request has been fulfilled?
Can I use a sequential key binding like Ctrl-x Ctrl-s in Sublime Text?
IP Address 0.0.0.0 is used or not?
issues with referential integrity (access 2007)
clearing Zombie-cookies
How to see the video from the webcam on the laptop?
Do all USB 3.0 micro cables use that weird double connector on the small end?
How can I disable new mail icon in one specific email account in Microsoft Office 2013?
why do i keep getting the same $SHELL even i am on a different shell already
Google can locate you with WiFi data, but how do the small companies do it?
Upgrade from Windows 7 to Win10, what happens?
disable incognito mode in ChromeOS (ChromeBook)
TeamCity 9 - Disable user registration
Windows 7 File Permissions, Security Tab, "Group or user names" SYSTEM group
Find bad shortcut files in windows
Transferring of printer settings to another windows installation
Where are Chromium extensions stored on Ubuntu Linux?
net config server displays
How Do I import emails in outlook 2010?
Stop on-screen keyboard from automatic popup
Importing Chrome bookmarks from HDD
Windows 8.1 not activating screen saver, turning off monitor, or sleep mode
Having trouble activation Office 365
Should fax machines use a DSL filter?
Apache Tomcat access denied error in windows XP
What's the difference between -sS and -sT on nmap?
Where Windows stores Internet Options?
How do I edit a missing template used in a Word document?
How do I install tuleap on windows7?
Inserting specific number of rows in Excel
Geany comment block format
Adding a Bookmark Table in a Document
How can I highlight all captions in word 2013
Windows 8 People app without a delete option
How is the CPU initialized by clock ticks?
Basic DHCP Leasing
Where does Chrome save its bookmarks on Windows 8.1?
Unexpected error while activating windows 8: No DNS Server configured for local system
What's the fastest bandwidth WiFi can reach?
How to go about temporarily disabling McAfee Internet Security?
Edit Microsoft Word 2007 table of contents indent?
How do I allow multiple people to open my Access database?
Deleting specific rows/columns from excel
How to boot in verbose boot for Windows 10?
What's the difference between a Hidden Administrator Account and normal Administrator account in Windows 10?
How to change your ssh & filezilla password on ovh?
How does one get an admin account on windows 8, with both accounts as Standard?
Adding a bend to a straight connector in Microsoft Visio 2013
Where is my gpgconf file on Windows?
Kernel-power error, automatic reset the computer
Adding dates to Microsoft Office 2013
How do we install new libraries for c++ mingw?
will I be able to log into a hidden account on windows 8
How to create junctions in win7 with gui?
How are clock rate measured and what does it mean?
How to copy deleted text in MS Word
Interpreting the 'metric' column in routing table
How can I create complicated shortcuts in Geany?
How do I import UDL into Notepad++?
Changing Photoshop resize keyboard shortcut
Can you install Windows as a dual-boot on a computer with only Linux installed?
What firmware/hardware mechanism enables force-shutdown?
Powershell auto complete settings.
No internet connection because of "error 797 modem was not found"
Basic Disk and Dynamic Disk vs. Primary Partition and Extended Partition and Logical Partition
Are there well known HTTP-only sites?
How can I convert .doc to .txt without getting a bunch of garbage in my txt file?
lenevo thinkpad 11e password reset
Defrag Terms Description
Cisco IOS XR: What is an "IID"?
Windows 10 > Control Panel > Mail > Explorer.exe > Appliction not Found
How do I use Msg.exe to send messages on Windows 7?
Window in window term
Completely disable printing in Google Chrome
TextMate restore last session/remember opened files
windows xp, ntfs, reset corrupted folder permissions
How to edit the (metadata) "comments" field of a folder?
32 bit Windows on 64 bit hardware for 32 bit apps
Browser Extension to check distance between elements
How to configure cURL to use always use a SOCKS proxy?
How do I map extensions in SublimeText (Is there a way I can map Sublime Text to treat mjs as js)
What will log file be written when the hostname is changed?
Copying image from word document seems to be lossy
Remove autosuggestion in FF quantum using about config
What does the "Access IBM" button do on old IBM laptops?
What does error code mean "ioerror; Offending Command:image mask ]%%
Security by encrypting a hard drive without additional PIN when using Windows Truecrpyt?
Binary Translation not working in VMware Workstation 12
What are the text used to search specific fields in Windows Search and Outlook called?
chsh: Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges
How do I search a page using a regular expression in Firefox (Quantum versions)?
Unattended Eclipse update
Bundle Chrome with particular extensions
How to configure Cisco Aironet 1200 in windows 10?
In Lotus Notes 9 How do you manually run rules you've written on your inbox, without installing any other plugins / software?
Rename Outlook Calendar item title
Enable xml files in outlook owa
My Software dll patches are not updated on windows 10
How to build imapsync for windows?
Where does CPU store instruction after decoding?
Google Chrome 64 / 67 different behavior for HTTP2
what to do when vs-code remote C++ debugging asks to set gnutarget format-name
distinction between volume and partition (terminology)
Keyboard shortcut to copy from below in Excel (opposite of Ctrl+D)
Restore possibly bricked WRT54GL (possibly lost IP address)
Touch bar auto-complete in Google Chrome
How to show information about revocation in key listing
Find the part of the string that distinguishes a string in one cell from a string in another cell
Qutebrowser - defining keybinds with a one-liner (instead of config file)
syslog : How can I filter syslog messages on windows 10?
How can I programmatically access the region of a Windows computer?
Rehash of a solution for cygwin/gfortran that does not work
How to support more than 500 users at one time on a WiFi network
Blinking power button in yellow color on a Dell OptiPlex 7010
Visual Studio - Change colors from blue to purple
XP64 2 XP64 install software using WMI
gpg - difference --encrypt-to and --recipient
No option to disable/enable Outlook notifications in Windows 10 settings
The format of the recovery password provided is invalid 0x80310035
is there a way to look for all commands in CentOS
Numbered/Ordered List In Microsoft Visio 2013?
macOS - virtual memory limit (architectural or practical)?
Scanstate error 71 while running on win 10 unit with user having elevated access
How to disable Chrome PDF Viewer in the latest version (72)
Uncorrectable sector count 1, pending sectors 0, reallocated 0 on two drives for years - why uncorrectable sectors were not reallocated?
How can I view my Instagram backup data in a friendly way?
HP Probook 450 G3 Boot Failure
Set and print content of environment variable in cmd.exe subshell?
How do anti-virus programs start at Windows boot?
Outlook rewrites all links in my email to go through Microsoft servers
How is a process defined as running in background?
Unable to Unregister WinzIp Self Extractor License Key
Can you run PoE Cat6 alongside standard Cat6 cables?
What does monitor brightness spec refer to?
MS Word 2016: Table is splitting across pages even though set not to
i want to reuse vagrant after i shutdown ubunto in Vertual box :
Want to delay startup of program but can't find it in Task Scheduler
How do TLD DNS registries and registars maintain the TLD zone file?
Windows: how to get start tool to override a local start.exe?
How much space does a GPT partition table take up?
How do I install Java DB on Windows 10?
CMD cipher /e on a folder output "Request not supported"
Is the facial recognition feature in Windows 10 Photos local or cloud?
Adding a path to login.conf in Bash / FreeBSD
How to disable high volume warning dialog?
Microsoft Visio Page settings
Which Android-x86 download to choose? (i686, x86_64, k49)?
Excel Window Top search box. How to hide?
Motherboard HDMI Version
What does TCP packet [P.] flag means in tcpdump's output?
How to predefine file/directory parameter to xcopy
How to tell if a distro was made using Gentoo
Where can I find the icons used for Music, Pictures, Videos etc. folders in Win10?
Does Home edition of windows 10 encrypt files?
MacOS Mojave - remove PHP installation from php-osx.liip.ch
Are there any recognised standards for Miracast devices?
What is the equivalent of "restore system" on mac?
Which version of Microsoft Office introduced the ability to edit and save to PDF files?
When is the TCP receive window advertised?


Do you wish to share links to these answers and/or a screenshot of them for those who can’t see deleted questions. While I recognize this question is specifically about those questions context might be helpful

@Ramhound: It's not my intention to point fingers at anyone. I'm trying to open a discussion with the moderators which might in the future prevent such unpleasantness as I experienced.

Without context I cannot say if these answers you describe were plagiarism, however, if these answers didn’t quote and cite the reference and provide some sort of original content I would deem them as nothing but a signpost.

@Ramhound i believe the posts that were deleted do indeed provide sources for where the content came from, but the problem is that is all they really are. They give nothing more than a quote and a link, which from an academic perspective is essentially the same as plagiarism, in that it demonstrates no awareness of the subject at hand. There was no original content, no real value to them beyond a cursory Google search and copied content.

@Mokubai - So in other words they were low quality.  Submitting substantial low quality content is suspension worthy in itself but were these examples plagiarism (I can’t say). How you quote and cite material is universally accepted throughout academia. We all have done it at least once, so not doing it properly, isn’t excusable. You can quote and cite as much material as you want in college but if you never summarize anything it’s nothing more than someone else’s words which is plagiarism. Wrote 5,000 reports as a MBA student and 2,500 was quoted from material and rest were my own words.

@Ramhound turnitin probably has stricter conditions than we do.

My problem with this question is that it comes across more as trying to break out the pitch-forks and organise a witch hunt instead of having a constructive discussion on whether your posts actually constitute plagiarism. Some (friendly) argument and discussion that people could actually give feedback and work on would be a useful point to have come from. Instead you already know you are right so everyone else is wrong and out to get you, which is patently not the case. I'd have hoped more of a constructive approach from one of the pillars of the community.

"Was this justified?" "Are these posts plagiarism?" and posting examples of the questions would have been something that the community could have discussed the various merits of. Instead this isn't any kind of discussion, it's an ultimatum that we should bow to your will instead of the larger community. I haven't downvoted (yet) but at the moment it seems that at least some people have issue either with the tone or content of your question, and honestly I can see why people would downvote it..

"You're citing academical standards, which have no bearing on the issue at all." - It absolutely has bearing on the issue.  Those academical standards are reasonable. I will repeat what I have said in the past, an answer which just contains information that was copied and pasted from a website, is not helpful to the community. I am still waiting on these examples of answers, which I presume you argue to not be plagiarism, to determine if there is anything I agree with in this question. Your last edit is just more complaints which in my eyes are unjustified.

Your complaint you were not warned before you were suspended, as been pointed out, you had been suspended for plagiarism in the past.  So your not going to be warned, before each suspension, if what caused you to be suspended continues to happen.  I have been suspended before for rude responses, I corrected that behavior, by copying and pasting close reasons instead of using my own words. I also bail on any conversation that makes me "scream into a pillow".  I also carry a travel pillow with me at all times....

@Ramhound: No problem, I have added one small list to my answer.

So I was actually only intererested in your 4 answers.  I have looked at 4 dozen of those answers, and everyone, really should contain more than just "here is some external information" but everyone I have noticed is from 2014.

@Ramhound: Yes, as I said there's some problem with the indexes of later years, where I get many wrong pointers to answers that are not by DavidPostill. The URLs should be by ascending date order and the latest is from 2020. I'm sure I have seen as many such answers of his in the last years, but the query doesn't give them. Actually, it's because I have seen these answers by DavidPostill that I dared write my 4 answers. It's late here, so I'll add links to my 4 deleted answers tomorrow.

@harrymc those indexes weren't needed to begin with. No one was asking for proof that other people were doing it, the only thing people were asking for was your questions. I can't help but think if you'd have had some honest introspection and come from a point of "Did these questions warrant a suspension?" then there could have been some constructive discussion. Maybe as a community we could do better, maybe we could define a better set of guidelines to say whether or not this does constitute plagiarism. As it stands you're asking "what about that guy?" which feel disingenuous.

It would have been far better and more constructive to look to the future and ask questions based on what we can do going forwards rather than justifying previous behaviour based on other peoples actions. "Is this kind of answer acceptable?" Some would say yes, other would say no. But phrasing the question better would include other people in the discussion. "If not then what do we expect from people going forwards?" Could let the community weigh in on what we would like answers to be and what standards are expected from everyone. Build a better future, don't just drag everyone down.

@Mokubai: This is a good advice, but doesn't answer what happened. I can't in all honesty ignore the fact that SU has unclear rules that are being applied in a selective manner. The example of a moderator (a good moderator) that has a hundred times more quote-only answers than me still sticks in my throat. I think that the moderators should be more open to criticism and to admitting to error. Practically, I think that moderator Journeyman Geek should apologize, but I don't think this is ever going to happen.

... With so many quote-only answers on SU, I think that de-facto, the definition of quote-only answers as plagiarism should be avoided. This is the main purpose of my post.

Moderators should absolutely be open to constructive criticism. Your argument is just "but what about this guy". There is no constructive element to it beyond "I'm right, you are wrong and this other guy posted answers before he was a mod" I get that you are angry about being suspended, but you are entirely focused on the idea that someone wronged you and someone else does what you did instead of asking "Hey, going forwards could we handle this better?" You are so focused on winning the game that you do not see the community around it.

@Mokubai: You're missing the point, although I can see it's easy to think so. I'm saying constructively that there is nothing wrong with a quote-only answer if it fully answers the question. I'm repeating that I like the answers by DavidPostill and wish him only good. The format of an answer is immaterial, and using it as the main criteria in deleting and suspending is just wrong. Yes, I'm personally angry because it happened to me, but advising me to forgive and forget just leaves the question open. I think you should look at it in a more general manner than just my personal motives.

... Which leaves still open my above proposition, which seems to be totally ignored in all of this.

@harrymc your proposition is not "ignored", it is just that it is only a small part of your question by volume and there is so much else to unpack. The general idea of downvotes on meta is "we disagree with you" so I would assume that no one wants what you propose.

@Mokubai: What do the moderators want? Don't you think that in view of the large number of quote-only answers, calling it plagiarism is de-facto impossible?

Moderators need to stop the hypocrisy, I pointed this out a long time ago about the bias of them being allowed to do something but suspending others for the same thing they are guilty of. I have no problem going through every one of those questions and voting to delete them. Do unto others as you want done until you without reading all the noise it is really really simple. Mods are going to be bias with other mods on SU in particular. If a mod was fair, they would start deleting those same sort of plagiarized post which other mods on SU write point blank period, otherwise, you are bias.

That's assume we've got axes to grind - or are on some sort of witch-hunt. We deal with these on the basis of flags, or what we come across.  We can't suspend other mods anyway - but where a mod's fallen short on something like this we do have conversations on what's expected. What we're not going to do is single out a user's posts specifically to find a reason to suspend them. And what's essentially dealing with criticism with what feels like personal attacks and whataboutism feels off. There's aspects of site/network culture I don't like - I just deal with it.

@JourneymanGeek: Question : How many users have you suspended for plagiarism because of quote-only answers? (I mean, besides me). Some examples would be good.

We don't discuss suspensions without the express permission of the user involved. So, no, we're not going to share that.

@Mokubai: Last message. I see the position of the moderators here as untenable. You're saying in effect: There are a hell of a lot of quote-only answers on SU, but we reserve ourselves the right to select a small number of them, declare them as plagiarism and punish the user, according to criteria that we won't share, and we won't accept complaints. Is that reasonable or a position that is possible to defend?

@harrymc - "Which leaves still open my above proposition" - If "A quote which is fully accredited and formatted as a quote, is not plagiarism.", then I do not agree with the proposition. You can quote something but if you do not properly cite your source then it can still be considered plagiarism. Here is my thought, these answers which were deleted and have not been shared, were likely low quality answers. So I could agree that while those answers were not an example of plagiarized content, they were low quality

@Ramhound: With "fully accredited" I mean that full credit was given to the author. For a book this would be author name, book name, and page number. For an internet post/article this would be at least a link. I can make the wording more specific if you feel it necessary. And I promised you the links to my deleted answers, but I can find only one, the other three have disappeared from my deleted answers list, maybe undeleted. For the moment, it seems that I was suspended for one quote-only answer.

@harrymc my position, if you actually try to read my comments, is to look to what we can improve for the future. What I would propose is actually asking the community their opinion on whether we accept these kinds of answers or not. If so we simply move on, if not then we draw a line in the sand and say "from this point onwards..." that is pretty far from "untenable" in my opinion. At no point have I advocated for mods being the final arbiter for justice. It was you who decided we are operating in bad faith as far as I can see, I want the community to decide, not you or I. I'm done here.

@Mokubai: My position exactly, and exactly what I'm trying to achieve here (while possibly being misunderstood) - the moderator shouldn't decide on plagiarism. No more messages.

@harrymc - I have voiced my opinion on nearly 150 of the answers you provided a link to, in my opinion, I would have liked them to be more than a signpost. However, trying to improve hundreds of answers which are signposts, submitted more than 5 years ago isn't a productive use of community time.  I expect an answer to be more than a signpost.  In this one example I would argue the question shouldn't have been answered by anyone.  At a minimum I would have wanted to see the reason you thought the comment that Aiml3ssCalam1ty made was accurate.  I certainly don't agree with it.

@harrymc.... In case it helps ease your pain, I too was suspended for this a long time ago after seeing DP and others reference and cite source material verbatim appropriately by I believe 'my favorite of all time mod across all SE sites then and still now [the champion] Journeyman Geek'; however, a Community Manager overrode the decision and unsuspended me after I reached out and they agreed that it was overkill. I believe this was my post SU meta follow up on the topic: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13351/does-attributing-alone-prevent-a-plagiarism-suspension... Do not verbatim only

Also, if a potential answer/solution does consist of verbatim cited sources, try to have more than one and write a lot of other verbiage between each I see advice 1 states to do x, y, z in a nutshell that makes sense that it may work but I cannot test it here is cited source for main points, then quote. Try to have more than just one, and write why you think it is a good potentially helpful for the OP. Some strategy like that. I got hit once, and never again so far but I do try to keep content being good quality most of the time in my answer/question posts across all sites. Welcome back!

@Mokubai: Constructive idea: Align SU with the SO policy - Are "quote-only" answers allowed? : Occasional quoting is suffered, quoting as principal method is not. This will reduce tensions with users (see above comment by user Vomit IT). Only answer my comment if you're considering this seriously.

@harrymc that would be my personal preference, but even then it should not be "alignment" but proper enforcing of what is already in the help center. Near the end of https://superuser.com/help/referencing is an important paragraph: "Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content."

@Mokubai: I don't see a big conflict. "Often" is not the same as "always", leaving room for some moderator appreciation. It might be taken to relate to the user using quoting too often. SE has exactly the same sentence but its interpretation is evidently different (as in my above link which could be adopted by SU). This interpretation is purely up to the moderators and doesn't need a Meta decision (it was so on SO).

Harry - Clear guidelines and consistent enforcement are vital for maintaining a healthy community. Your suggestion aims to address this issue constructively. I suggest making a secondary post spin off of this one and be concise and to the point for those sort of main points without all the other noise as you see the reaction. You are highest rep SU account thus far and this comes with an implicit expectation that you already know things and are the expert. It is bias to assume your high rep makes you know it all or already know better in these sort of instances—I raised the question long ago.

Obviously this is not plagiarism. It's something more like "low quality" in terms of terms used here and definitely shouldn't be encouraged too much, as such answers tend to be underanalyzed and often also inaccurate. If it was up to me, I'd require at least 2-3 original sentences per answer. But you are 100% correct this needs to be in rules, written quite clearly.

@Destroy666 - It’s not clear there actually wasn’t plagiarism, the answers from this suspension were never provided, only one example was provided and it was a low quality copy and paste answer. They were conveniently not available.  However, it doesn’t matter, despite being warned NOT to submit low quality copy and paste answers that pattern clearly was repeated due to their current account status. The length of the suspension this time followed the guidance for suspension length.

@Destroy666 That's a great idea. Its already included in the 'referencing' part of the help  and an old MSO post that we point people at in a moderator message. however . We don't 'really' have a low quality answers as a stock suspension reason- so its between "Plagiarism" in terms of not meeting referencing requirements, or "other" . It is in the rules. That said - we try to provide the person suspended with details of why, so the people involved have a clear idea what went wrong.


Proposed resolution : A quote which is fully accredited and formatted as a quote, is not plagiarism.
This definition is in line with all the world's dictionaries and all the world's legal sources.

 source: the question 
It'd be good to cite all your sources here, or at least show a modicium of research. I've tended to consider the standards many universities use as best practices and I really liked the explanation given here
I'll quote 2 relevant passages to ensure that should the source be lost, its still accessible here,and so a reader dosen't need to go off site to read them. Notice the bulk of this post is original material, and my 'own' work is a backbone, not a scaffold

Students are often told to use direct quotes when they feel the original author’s phrasing expresses the idea so well that no better expression can be found. This is good advice but be sure to do more than just string quotes together with a few transition sentences. Even if every quote is adequately cited, the overall paper will feel plagiarized since the student has not written anything new.

 source: https://libguides.csusm.edu/academic_honesty/direct_quotation 
Now consider this for answers. An answer should be more than stringing together a quote with some scaffolding. A great answer is a lot more than googling the question

Each field of study has specific guidelines about direct quotation. For instance, direct quotation is often discouraged in the sciences, which prefer paraphrasing. Students can check with their professor on the preferred style in their discipline.

 source: https://libguides.csusm.edu/academic_honesty/direct_quotation 
I'd consider technology a science more than an art, and in the age of chatbots and such, value adds to an answer - building on your own experiences, and tailoring an answer to a question as much as possible would be nice.
As such, you've begun your post with an inaccuracy. All is a very very broad statement, one might even call it hyperbole.

Why was I suspended for so long for a rule that doesn't exist in a
written form?

 source: the question 
This was linked in the stock moderator message you received https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321326/674571 - Its part of the standard moderator message template sent to any users.
In the interests of full disclosure - its 30 days cause we followed the standard escalation, and this is your second suspension for this. It seems a complete misrepresentation to make it seem like there wasn't any prior interactions, and we just jumped to 30 days.
I'd also point you at the relevant help section - these rules exist in written form. It might be useful to acquaint yourself with these. While you linked it I feel like you might have missed the critical portion of it.

Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.

 source: https://superuser.com/help/referencing 
To borrow a term from tabletop RPGs, it very much is Rules as Written, as well as intended. These answers were practically complete text
Its probably worth noting that over time I've helped draft parts of the rules here, and spent as much time on meta as here, so I've no idea what you actually mean by unwritten rules. The rules are written and available
We've also generally not gone looking for specific violations since that would be unfairly targeting a user, but that's explained later.

Since I had some time on my hands these last 30 days, I have studied the Stack Exchange API and have written a program that scans all answers on SU and checks whether they are quote-only.

 source: the question 
This would indicate you're aware of the standards expected - which is excellent  It might also be a great opportunity to review and improve your own posts to meet the standards.
I'd note we don't have any tooling that particularly helps with this and if its actually accurate,  there's some mods who might find this sort of thing useful.

The moderator that suspended me has written enough quote-only answers to be suspended himself.

 source: the question 
You're not going to know which moderator suspended you. This is precisely why in general, a moderator message is signed by the team. It used to be signed off by the mod who sent it, but this is precisely why its not. People trying to intimidate mods and all that. It seems a very loaded statement and presumes, in addition to knowing which mod sent you the message, that there's an ongoing pattern of misbehaviour.
An interesting side question might be what happens if your script is wrong and there's literally no other way to answer the question, or it wasn't plagiarism at all.

Another moderator has written many quote-only answers. I remark that his answers are to the point and were often accepted by the posters. I'm puzzled by him not coming forward to explain to the other moderator that quoting is not plagiarism.

 source: the question 
Quoting with appropriate sourcing isn't always plagiarism - it is a necessary, but not completely sufficient thing to avoid plagiarism. It's not a replacement for using your own words and tailoring your answer to the question. Hypothetically in such a conversation, one of the things I'd point out is that it sets a poor example for other users.

There are thousands of quote-only answers on SU and it's simply unfeasible to delete them, as many are upvoted or accepted by the posters. Deleting these answers will leave their questions in a chaotic state.

 source: the question 
We deal with these as they are flagged - and by their own merits. In some cases we might find something that was surfaced by smoke detector, take a look and find its not spam, and the link used might have tripped a blocklist.
If you feel plagiarism is an problem that should be solved, maybe its worth going through there in your spare time, and updating these to better, self contained answers that are not purely quotes.
That said, do you really want to be the guy who basically decided to ruin a bunch of people's day cause you were unhappy with a moderator decision? If you choose to flag based on using an automated script to find and flag things, it could potentially be a code of conduct violation as well.
We're going to expect you to read each one, as we do, and make a determination, and generally if we find someone's wasting our time, we're unhappy.

And most important : SU is said to be a democracy. A democracy is ruled according to a set of written rules, and only by those rules. The rules apply to everyone and even for the persons in authority. How can we have in SU unwritten rules that are applied or not at the discretion of the moderator?

 source: the question 
I'd point you at the theory of moderation. As a moderator, I generally consider suspensions to be a last resort, when other things have failed. Community health as a whole is a priority, and if something isn't written down, but is hurting the community, we'll take the appropriate action. This isn't the case though. We've followed the rules as written.
Should we overstep - an appeal to the community team would be a countercheck. While I'm unsure if I'd be overstepping if I said this was done, maybe it'd be good to reveal if this was and what the outcome of this appeal.

Your goal is to guide the community with gentle -- but firm -- intervention. Respect your fellow community members at all times; demonstrate fairness and impartiality in your actions.

 source: the question 
When we suspend someone, except in exceptional situations, there's generally a written rule. That said, democracies are not police states either.
Our goal isn't an overarching order, but rather to balance the needs of the people with practical necessities. Would it be nice if everyone posted original content? Absolutely. Are we going to hunt down every situation where someone has posted these? Not really.
We do not have a goal of compliance to very strict rules as written. We'd like people to understand and adhere to the spirit of the rules.
We intervene when there's a problem. While we keep rules as written as guidance, there are some situations where we need the flexibility to act on the rules as intended, or deal with unexpected situations. This isn't one of those though.
There's checks on us - via contacting the company as well. It is not, to quote a local political party for me "ownself check oneself". We also discuss such situations internally.
With newer versions of moderator messages we also include examples/links to what was specifically done wrong. When we suspend someone once, we don't expect to need to suspend them again.

If the moderators choose instead to uphold this plagiarism rule, explicitly or by inaction, I intend to fully cooperate with them by publishing on Meta SU in bunches the links to all the quote-only answers on SU, and I will report periodically on the progress done by the moderators in cleaning SU of plagiarism.

 source: the question 
I was going to offer to fix any of my questions that weren't up to standard or delete. That said this sounds suspiciously like a threat. If anyone else finds one of my answers are not up to scratch in this regard, anywhere on the network, y'all know where to find me, and I'll have an open offer to delete or fix up any of my past mistakes that offend.

I encourage getting rid of any answer that doesn’t meet our minimum quality expectations, but if you are going to use a script to find that content, you better be darn sure that content is what you say it is. Which is still the reason I haven’t signed up for automatically flagging spam even if it’s %99.999999 accurate

I have answered this in my post.

I have now added some URLs to my answer. I wait to see how many of them you will delete as "low quality". Would you accuse your fellow moderator of plagiarism?

After looking at nearly 100 of those links, I would say, the community would not be harmed by the removal of the vast majority of those answers.  However, I don't feel trying to improve nearly 200 answers, most are 7 years old would provide any substantial contribution to the community.  In other words, these answers helped the authors of those questions, but none of those questions have hundreds of votes or hundreds of thousands of views.

You wrote "Quoting with appropriate sourcing isn't plagiarism". AFAIK, OP has always quoted with appropriate sourcing. Yet, OP's "account is temporarily suspended for plagiarism".  Why?

We do not discuss suspensions without express permission of the user involved. I have provided a comprehensive explanation of our expectations - with the goal of avoiding the need for further suspensions. Its worth reading the earlier part about not completely copying sources, and the later part about it not being sufficient on its own, rather than cherrypicking a single sentence fragment. This post is best seen as a entire work, rather than a series of standalone quotations from other sources.

@JourneymanGeek There are several topics at hand, so for now I am trying to narrow down on only one topic: the use of the term plagiarism. Forget about everything else. According to all dictionaries I've seen, quoting with appropriate sourcing is not plagiarism. Yet, OP's "account is temporarily suspended for plagiarism". Why?

We don't discuss suspensions. We've communicated with harry over why. We've communicated our expectations in general above.

The discussion would be shorter if people were able to listen.  I'm going to lock the comments on this a week, and come back and clean this up. The comments are going around in circles and there's literally nothing 'new' to say.

Trying to make sense of this as someone who is more or less an outsider, I have to say, this answer is awful. You say there are definitions of plagiarism under which a SE answer clearly formatted as a quote and citing its source can be "plagiarism"... then don't cite any. (None of your quoted or linked sources actually support this contention.) You say the rules are written down, but don't point to any that distinguish between kosher quote-only answers and verboten ones, nor do you set out here any criteria by which to distinguish the two - just that cases are judged on their "merits". [1/2]

[2/2] Perhaps worst is that you weigh against the OP flagging similar answers by other users on the basis that it would just "ruin a bunch of people's day" to delete other such answers from the site. What?! It's one thing not to think it's worth putting in the enforcement effort, but that doesn't seem to be what you're saying - instead you seem to simply be conceding it would be an outright bad thing to enforce the rule equally against answers posted by users other than the OP here. But then why was his content any different?


Proposed resolution : Quoting cannot be called plagiarism.

Any dictionary would 100% agree with that. I saw that you got suspended for quoting (since I saw your great answer got deleted right before you got suspended) and I was outraged to see that mods defamed you by falsely accusing you of plagiarism.
It's not even a matter of a "proposed resolution". If someone falsely accused me of plagiarism, that would be an easy day at the court (since in my work, plagiarism is a career killer, rightfully so). It's the same as falsely accusing someone of racism by redefining the meaning of racism (for more examples, just replace plagiarism/racism by any other word).
See Why was my answer deleted for plagiarism, despite mentioning the source? for a similar debate on SO where people agreed that quoting is not plagiarism,  or just look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism:

Plagiarism is the representation of another person's language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions as one's own original work [1,2,3].

which is supported by these dictionaries:


From the 1995 Random House Compact Unabridged Dictionary:

use or close imitation of the language and thoughts of another author and the representation of them as one's own original work

qtd. in Stepchyshyn, Vera; Nelson, Robert S. (2007). Library plagiarism policies. Assoc. of College & Resrch Libraries. p. 65. ISBN 978-0-8389-8416-1.

^ From the Oxford English Dictionary:

The action or practice of taking someone else's work, idea, etc., and passing it off as one's own; literary theft.


^ The American Heritage Dictionary (5th ed.), defines plagiarize thus: “To reproduce or otherwise use the words, ideas, or other work of another as one’s own, or without attribution.”



Furthermore, quote-only answers can be helpful:

There's no point in paraphrasing if the
quote properly addresses the question, which it does in many cases
because Internet contains many texts. I've asked a fair amount of
questions on SE and from time to time the answer was simply a quote.
Reasons to quote:

Human time is precious.
Not adding some noise to the original text.
A quote from a reputable source is more convincing than a paraphrase of it by some random Stack Exchange user.
As the OP I don't want to read both a paraphrase and the original text. Waste of time, just give me straight the original if
appropriate.
The point of SE is sharing knowledge, and a quote is a piece of knowledge.



This isn't SO, and I'd point out the response from a mod got  ~2x the upvotes you have, even if it mattered so... details are pretty important

@JourneymanGeek When someone is accused of plagiarism because they properly quoted a source, I don't need details: this is a false accusation. Both SO and SU use English.

For what it may help here, I agree of course with your answer : quoting/citing is distinct from plagiarism. It can be called "site rules" or anything else but not plagiarism. The whole point of my post was to get the moderators to get their terms straight and also to get their act together, punishing me and others while a moderator has with total impunity a hundred times more such answers than anyone else.

@JourneymanGeek vote crowing rings kinda hollow at the moment, and looks bad too.

I mean, someone's quoting a post from another site, claiming its the practice they have there. Only, It wasn't what the site is using. In that context, I'd say the voting shows their community dosen't agree with it as much, and isn't a great indicator of best practices. Its a 6 month old post that got bumped up so - even if I was worried about looking bad, its a bit late for it. I think I've communicated quite extensively on my views on the topic already.

If you really can't add anything to an answer you find elsewhere, it should be a comment, not an answer. Answers should be tested by whoever writes them, so at the very least, you can add something like: "I have found this solution of XY, which I have tested and can confirm it resolves your issue."

Get off your high horse and get over it already.
I think your demands that community guidelines be changed to suit your needs really reeks of entitlement. You have about 484,000+ reputation, yet this all reads like the tantrums of a new user.
Meaning, I would not respect any opinion you currently have because your proverbial “Spit don’t stink…”
You are essentially kvetching that you are beyond reproach and are utterly flawless in your interactions with this community. And we should be so lucky to have you as a community member.
To me that alone warrants a suspension more than anything: A community is more than just one voluminous poster.
In my interactions with you, you have generally taken any criticism as a personal affront and you show utterly no signs of basic human humility. And on the rare occasion your answer is utterly wrong — like one time you claimed in an answer “Apache will use the full power of Nginx” (Which anyone who uses Apache and Nginx knows is completely wrong.) — you typically delete that answer and move on.
The quantity of contributions you have made does not justify this arrogance on your part. Especially since you seem to favor “quantity” over “quality” when you post answers.

Not so - you're ignoring the fact that my proposition has nothing to do with me and is only future-looking. It's motivated by a personal event, cert, but its aim is to modify site rules to set quote-only answers as acceptable. What I stretch is the fact that, de facto, quote-only answers exist in large numbers on SU, so calling then plagiarism is just ridiculous.

@harrymc - Here is the thing.  You have a habit of submitting an answer, and the moment it receives a downvote, you delete it.  I won't hold that behavior against you, even though I think it's toxic behavior, that the SE software should not allowed.  It's my personal opinion that a contribution should not be deleted by the author unless it's peer reviewed by the community. With that out of the way, you have been warned about low quality copy and paste answers in the past, here is when you last had this discussion in 2020

@Ramhound: Untrue. I delete an answer only if it's proven wrong or I have misunderstood the question or if interfacing with the poster becomes too painful. I leave downvoted answers without deleting them if I don't see them as wrong. You may check if you like.

@harrymc - You should be editing those incorrect answers in that case.  There are several users which often will delete an answer they have submitted once it receives a single downvote.  I rarely provide any comment about my downvote, for those users, because it's proven to be a waste of my time to provide feedback.

@Ramhound: I stopped being worried about downvotes a long time ago, if they come without a comment that makes me doubt the correctness or relevancy of my answer. I will delete an answer if I'm convinced it's unfixable or the context is too painful, I don't need a downvote for that.

I will say clear guidelines and consistent enforcement are vital for maintaining a healthy community which is what the real question should be about addressing.

Giacomo1968, your entire post is a personal aggression against the OP. You don't address the fact that the OP was accused of plagiarism whereas they only clearly quoted some text.  And you don't address the fact that the OP was suspended for doing so in a few answers, whereas a mod did the same in ~200 answers.

We don't discuss suspensions unless the suspended user brings it up but when they have - while a little blunt, feels like it reflects the issues here from the point of view of a community member.  Lets just consider for a moment that OP's done personal attacks on at least two moderators in his response, and I've yet to be told of one post I've done that needs fixing up on my end. And semantics aside - there's been more than one moderator message/suspension for the same thing. Its not like we just hit him with suspensions without cause

@JourneymanGeek ok. did OP plagiarize?

OP was informed of what was needed to be rectified.  We've pointed out what was in the help section. We've done our part. There's an entire answer explaining what the issue is. My comments were about 'why' this response was left in place. I think my 'ideal' expectations to be followed going forward are very clearly set out in my answer.

@JourneymanGeek For the OP, you've certainly explained the situation well. For most people, reading this post (https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13351/why-attribution-alone-cant-prevent-a-plagiarism-suspension) — including the question, all answers, and comments — will provide the clarity needed to understand and follow the rules of the topic. Regardless of historical content they may come across, that post clarifies the topic points people mainly seek. I've learned my lesson and aim to avoid past mistakes. While some may take it personally, the topic itself is straightforward for me now.

@FranckDernoncourt—"You don't address the fact that the OP was suspended for doing so in a few answers."—Here is the thing. HarryMC submits dozens of answers daily, which is perfectly fine, but he didn't have a few answers deleted. They had nearly a dozen answers directly deleted with regard to this single instance.

@Ramhound thanks, that would be a more informative answer. Still not plagiarism though, and a dozen quote-only answers is nowhere close to the other mod.

@FranckDernoncourt—This time around, There were only close to a dozen answers. There is a history and a pattern. I could likely find at least 500 quote-only answers submitted by Harry this year if I took the time to do so. The only reason I won't is because I have a feeling Harry won't be submitting quotes, only answers in the future. If that does happen I will be the first to flag them. I will also submit a comment linking to this very discussion.

@Ramhound Thanks, point taken. That'd be a good answer. It is still not plagiarism though (and imho quote-only answers can be helpful, but that's another debate).

The hostility in this answer appalls me, and frankly I don't know why it wasn't deleted by the mods. The OP posts a specific policy proposal and the response is multiple paragraphs of unrelated personal attacks on him, followed by another user piling on with more irrelevant personal attacks in the comments section, and the mods here allowed all this to stand? There is not a single sentence to be found in this answer that addresses the substantive merits or downsides of the OP's proposal, or even tries to. It ought to have been deleted on sight by whichever mod first laid eyes on it.

A little late but - considering the broader history of the user, and well, the accusations of moderatory abuse in the question, we felt it was generally a good idea to keep the posts reflecting the sentiments of regular users in place. We'd kinda hoped OP'd see the effect they'd had on the community, and honestly considering the personal attack in the question, one would argue by that merit, the entire question should go, but that raises accusations of censorship.

@JourneymanGeek The tone of the question certainly leaves something to be desired, but I see no outright "personal attack" in it besides pointing out the uneven application of the rule at stake, which is highly significant to both a discussion about the wisdom of enforcing it against the OP in particular and also to any discussion of what the rule should be.

I mean, I'm called out by name (and initially accused of plagiarism - Which , is a joke cause I'm very picky about these things in my answers). OP picked out posts by another mod specifically.  Not examples of plagiarism. Least on my part I feel OP had a personal attack. I'd also note - we treat OP exactly the same as any other user. OP would have gotten a stock or near stock mod message - and by his own admission has been suspended multiple times. I'd note the question isn't about guidance. Its demanding we recalibrate the rules "or else"

@JourneymanGeek No, he said you have posted many quote-only answers. Certainly you have multiple answers that primarily consist of blockquotes from sources and at least one that contains absolutely no information beyond what's blockquoted. Obviously this isn't an "accusation" because the OP thinks this is 100% fine (as do I and as do you); his question, which I cannot see an answer to in anything you've said despite your repeated insistence that the explanation is documented, is what distinguishes his primarily-quote-based answers from yours or David's.

fair. And considering the answer didn't work as per the feedback I got, and one of the links I quoted's dead, I'll see if I can fix or delete that answer. Looking at it, though, I'm unsure what I can add outside the primary source.

@JourneymanGeek If it's actually broken, then fixing or deleting seems usefu, but (IMO, and I infer OP would agree) not just because it's quote-only. It would be pointlessly harmful to purge all your or David's properly-attributed quote-only answers. What's missing from all the answers here is any discussion of what it was about the OP's answers that in your view warranted seeing them as a rules violation when other quote-only answers are evidently accepted as just fine. (I suspect from what has been said that the mod messages also didn't explain this, though I obviously cannot know.)

Also I'm curious - why the sudden interest in a roughly 6 month old post?

@JourneymanGeek I coincidentally stumbled across it while searching for discussions of a more-or-less unrelated issue, and felt strongly enough about what I saw to comment.

From my own perspective? That's not what the question was about. OP wanted to change the standards and my answer focused on that, and this one focused on the effect it has on how OP's viewed, and was a balance to franck's post. We didn't see any value in specifically going through questions here, but rather address the broader issues.

Reading the post, the replies, and the comments here it appears that, practically speaking, the Mods accept that a fully credited quote that is the majority or totality of an answer is valid, except when it isn't. There is an X factor at play here, and I am not in a place to judge that or its impact on the rightness of one side or the other. What it does do, though, is erode a little bit some of the trust I had in certain of the moderation staff. Not entirely sure what all this means, how it will impact; but I don't like it.

We're going to try our best to be evenhanded. We'll warn when its a first or even second offence. The problem is really when someone decides the rules (which are fairly similar networkwide) dosen't apply to them. The X factor here is - repitition and how you deal with feedback. I still consider a suspension a last resort, and subsequent suspensions are a result of either failures in communication or a unwillingness to take multiple attempts at feedback. I'd note this isn't OP's first post on the same topic.

On the other hand, I am not going to take kindly to what have felt like multiple attempts to pressure or intimidate moderators into a certain course of actions, which feel like the case here. We're not going to dig our heels in cause of this there's a lot of behind the scenes communications, and reviews by staff here. We've generally got a ton of oversight, above and below our levels of operation. Its needfully invisible but we're not just suspending high ranking users, or targetting people willy nilly. There's a process - least to people involved, as much visibility as possible

to what's wrong and what our expectations are. Our methods of operatons haven't changed much over time. Hopefully outside common sense - and both rules as written across the network (aka the COC and such), and the site, the X factor SHOULD be communicated to affected users based on the situation.
